# How to findcolumn in vector

Tags: java, vector

How to findcolumn in vector and change a specific column value to show something else on the JTable?

my code looks like this:

```
Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
while (rs.next()) {
    Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
    for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
        vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));                      
    }
    data.add(vector);
}
return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
```

Comment: Could you clarify your requirement? The intended requirement is unclear...

Comment: It is because when i build my Jtable, then i got all my data in the vector. but there is a column that i want to replace in the vector.
like if(status is equal to one, then show the string "is here")
instead of showing the variable 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `Vector<Map<String, Object>>` Structure to for your solution.

But if you do not want to use Map, then you can implement this solution.

Have an map which has Column Name and Column Index pair.

```
Map<String, Integer> columnNameIndexPair
```

Vector maintains insertion order, so in this case you can Insert objects in the vector. To retrieve data from vector, first find corresponding index from `columnNameIndexPair`, and get(index) element from vector.